# iphone : uitableview : contents of a cell change on scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have an array which I am using to furnish the contents of custom cell in table view
I dont know whats wrong but when I scroll a tableview the contants oc cell changes dynamically

Please help me to fix this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
MyIdentifier = @"tblCellView";
NSString *offendersImagePath = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
//NSLog(@"%@", dbPath);
offendersImagePath=[offendersImagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Images"];


CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if(cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = aCustomCell;
    aCustomCell=nil;
}

NSMutableArray *tempArray;//=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

tempArray=[offendersNamesList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);

offendersImagePath=[offendersImagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",[tempArray objectAtIndex:0]]];
NSLog(offendersImagePath);
[[cell offendersImageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:offendersImagePath]];
[cell.offendersNameLbl setText:[tempArray objectAtIndex:1]];
[cell.offendersViolation setText:[tempArray objectAtIndex:2]];
//[tempDictionary release];

//[cell setLabelText:[arryData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
return cell;
```

}

Comment: can you post code from cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is typically the problem in these kinds of problems is that you are not setting up the content in your cell correctly in the cellForRowAtIndexPath.  When a cell scrolls off the screen the system dumps it into a "Recycle Queue" (my term).  As new cells scroll onto the screen the system looks in this recycle queue for cells it can reuse.
`((CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];)`
If it does not find one it goes ahead and builds an entirely new one from scratch.  In your case, it looks like for whatever reason you are not setting up the cell content correctly and the changes you are seeing are recycled cells that have not been updated with the correct content.

I'm not sure exactly where you are going wrong but the code you are using for new cells is a little strange.  It should look more like this:

```
if(cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% what your issue is, but if it's items that have variable text length and the items on the cell aren't getting re-sized, it's because the sizings of the labels contained in the cell are not getting updated, just their text is getting changed.

A note about doing lookups in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, perhaps you should construct your array(of objects/dictionaries) in viewDidLoad, so as to be more efficient.

Another thing to note is your using .jpg files. It's more optimal to use .png files as they are crushed in size at compile time.

Also using NSMutableArray *tempArray; and hard-coded indexes is very bad practice, if something changes position in the array it means you have to change all your code. Try using a NSDictionary so as the keys are less likely to change.